# Rust & Rocket.rs - Build a layout system

Tags: rust, handlebars.js

I try to create a small website with [Rocket.rs](http://rocket.rs/) & Handlebar templating system. I want to create a global layout & include my content in the `<body>` tag

Here my code

```
templates/
├── layouts
│   └── main.html.hbs
└── pages
    └── home.html.hbs
```

Here my layout file

```
<!-- templates/layouts/main.html.hbs -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    {{~> page}}
</body>
</html>
```

And here my content

```
<!-- templates/pages/home.html.hbs -->
{{#*inline "page"}}
<h1>hello</h1>
{{/inline}}
{{~> (layouts/main)~}}
```

And my Rust code

```
// src/main.rs

#[get("/")]
fn home() -> Template {
    let map = ();
    Template::render("pages/home", &map)
}

fn main() {
    rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![home])
        .attach(Template::fairing())
        .launch();
}
```

How can I include *pages/home* into the global layout?

Comment: *but I don't suceed* — perhaps you would be so kind as to tell us what **actually happens**? Also, take a second to re-read over your question. You'll find that you've left incomplete data and added some garbage text in there.

Comment: Actually I had a blank page. The documentation for Rocket.rs & Handlebars system is verry poor. I don't know how to include global layout

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After hours of searching I founded my answer

For the layout it was good

```
<!-- templates/layouts/main.html.hbs -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    {{~> content}}
</body>
</html>
```

But for the page you need to do somethink like this

```
<!-- templates/pages/home.html.hbs -->
{{#*inline "page"}}
<h1>hello</h1>
{{/inline}}
{{~> layouts/main~}}
```